# How to make a method to wait for an object to get instantiates in java?

Tags: java, java-8

want the execution will wait until i get the token back. this class has few more methods which will also wait until the token received.

```
public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
        Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
    currentSubject = subject;
    currentCallbackHandler = callbackHandler;
    currentSharedState = (Map<String, Object>) sharedState;
    currentOptions = (Map<String, Object>) options;
    success = false;
    System.out.println("kousik level 0.1");
    
   
    SAMLToken token= null;
    WSSUtilFactory factory = null;
    
    try{
    synchronized (token) {
        while (token == null){
            wait(100);
            factory = WSSUtilFactory.getInstance();
            token = factory.getSaml20Token(); 
        }
        if(token != null)
            notifyAll();
    }
   }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your existing code?

Comment: Do I guess correctly that you problem is that you cannot synchronize on `null`?

Comment: `synchronized (token)` is `null` by default and will be changed within a block. So this is **not correct**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you cannot use `synchronize(null)`, I think you can try use an array instead, as the code shows below.

Annother problem is that you use the `synchronize` on a local variable, there is no race condition with other methods.

```
        SAMLToken token = null;
        WSSUtilFactory factory = null;
        final SAMLToken[] ref = new SAMLToken[] {token};

        try {
            synchronized (ref) {
                while (ref[0] == null) {
                    wait(100);
                    factory = WSSUtilFactory.getInstance();
                    ref[0] = factory.getSaml20Token();
                }
                if (ref[0] != null) {
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Question , I want the main thread to wait until I get the token back , how can it possible ?

Comment: 1. Set `final SAMLToken[] ref` as a global variables.
2. Set `final SAMLToken[] ref` as a parameter, and declare it in main thread.

Comment: 3. Try use some concurrent util(semaphore, lock, etc) insead synchronized, because method 1 and 2 will change the scope of `toekn`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility).

```java
public void main() {
    String token = waitForTokenAtMostSeconds(30);
}

private String waitForTokenAtMostSeconds(int seconds) {
    String token = waitAtMostSeconds(seconds, () -> factory.getSaml20Token());
    return Objects.requireNonNull(token, "Cannot find token");
}

private static <T> T waitAtMostSeconds(int seconds, Callable<T> supplier) {
    return Awaitility.await().atMost(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                     .until(supplier, Objects::nonNull);
}
```